# Published variable doesn't reload views

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've a view with a `@ObservedObject` which is my view model, inside this VM I have a `@Published`object. This one is supposed to reload view when it's modified.

here is my code :

```
struct SurveyPresentationView: View {

    @ObservedObject var VM:SurveyPresentationViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing : 0){
            NavigationWithBackButtonView(title: "surveys_upper_case")
            VStack(spacing: 0){
                HStack{
                    Text(VM.variable)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .modifier(OpenSansBoldModifier(fontSize: 16))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .onAppear(){
                self.VM.appear()
            }
        }
    }
}

class SurveyPresentationViewModel: ObservableObject {

    // MARK: - INIT -
    func appear()
    {
        variable = "ALL RIGHT"
    }

    // MARK: - PUBLISHED VALUES -
    @Published var variable:String = ""

}
```

the view isn't reload and my Text field stays empty ... did I missed something about published/observed/observable objects ?

Comment: it is always much easier for all reviewers if you post a reproducable example with startable code in here...so either please simplify your code or give us the rest like class for Occurence, OccurrenceManager...etc.

Comment: @Chris updated my code to a simplest one

Comment: Removing `NavigationWithBackButtonView` and `OpenSansBoldModifier` from your code works as expected.

Comment: @nayem ok I found something else, this with is the third one of a navigationView, if I place it in second position, it works .... in third it doesn't ...

Comment: Where do you init your VM property?